# Recursive function to find if a subset of the numbers in the input array can be added up to a give target value

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am writing a recursive function to find if a subset of the numbers in the input array can be added up to a give target value. However, the result is wrong.

`*a` is the array given
`n` is the length of `a[]`
The solution is stored in array `c[]`
`k` is the number of elements in `c[]`
`target` is the target number
`i` is an index, which is `0` when beginning

```
bool findNumTargetSum(int *a, int n, int *c, int &k, int target, int i)

{
    // Recursive function to find if a subset of the numbers in the input array
    // can be added up to a give target value.

    // Required input parameters include 
    //  - input array of integers and the length of the array
    //  - array for storing the solution, and length of the result array passed by reference
    //  - other parameters for the control of recursion

    // The input array is sorted in ascending order. This property may help to
    // improve the computation efficiency to some exend.

    // The function returns ture if a solution is found; otherwise returns false.

    c[k] = a[i];

    int total = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < k + 1; j++) {
        total += c[j];
    }

    if (i >= n)
        return false;

    if (total == target) {
        k += 1;
        return true;
    }

    else if (total < target) {
        i += 1;
        k += 1;
        findNumTargetSum(a, n, c, k, target, i);
    }

    else if (total > target) {

        k -= 1;

        if (k < 0)
            return false;
        findNumTargetSum(a, n, c, k, target, i);

    }
}

void part_2()
{
    // Test data: the array is sorted in ascending order.
    int a[] = { 8, 12, 20, 35, 36, 41, 55, 64, 72, 81 };
    int n = 10;

    int c[10];  // array for storing the solution
    int k = 0;  // k = number of elements in c[]

    cout << "\n-----------------------------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "Part-2: recursion and backtracking\n";

    cout << "Numbers in input list:\n";
    printArray(a, n);

    int total = sum(a, n);
    cout << "sum of the numbers in input list = " << total << endl << endl;

    bool success = false;

    for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)  // try 6 test cases
    {
        int target = total * i / 7 + 2;
        k = 0;

        success = findNumTargetSum(a, n, c, k, target, 0);

        if (success)
        {
            cout << "Numbers in input list that add up to " << target << " :\n";
            printArray(c, k);
        }
        else
            cout << "DO NOT find subset of numbers in input list that add up to " << target << endl << endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: `To find if a subset of the numbers in the input array can be added up to a give target value`- so just recursively make 2 calls, `with` and `without` where `with` subtracts from the target and `without` pushes target to next element in it's call as is. Complexity is exponential of course.

Comment: What do you return in the cases when the recursive functions are called? Or when none of the conditions are true? Not returning anything in a function declared to do so leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And edit your question to tell us *how* "the result is wrong". What result did you expect? What result did you get? And lastly please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your function `findNumTargetSum`. Logic was incorrect. Logic should be like: adding current element `a[i]` to the subset `c` or not adding current element `a[i]` to the subset `c`. Code is given below:

```
bool findNumTargetSum(int *a, int n, int *c, int &k, int target, int i)
{
    // Recursive function to find if a subset of the numbers in the input array
    // can be added up to a give target value.

    // Required input parameters include 
    //  - input array of integers and the length of the array
    //  - array for storing the solution, and length of the result array passed by reference
    //  - other parameters for the control of recursion

    // The input array is sorted in ascending order. This property may help to
    // improve the computation efficiency to some exend.

    // The function returns ture if a solution is found; otherwise returns false.

    if (i >= n)
        return false;

    // not taking ar[i] element
    bool found = findNumTargetSum(a, n, c, k, target, i+1);
    if(found == true) {
        return found;
    }

    // taking ar[i] element
    c[k] = a[i];
    int total = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < k + 1; j++) {
        total += c[j];
    }

    if (total == target) {
        k++;
        return true;
    }
    if (total < target) {
        k++;
        bool found = findNumTargetSum(a, n, c, k, target, i+1);
        if(found == true)
          return found;
        k--; 
    }
    return false;
}
```